# un-scope @ViewAccessScoped Beans on Tab close

Tags: deltaspike

I have a JSF-App with two `@ViewAccessScoped` Beans and two Pages/Views, one Bean for a Search, on Bean for details. The details Bean references the @ViewAccessScoped so the data available when I go back to the Search. No other CDI-References. The WindowRenderMode is `ClientWindowRenderMode.CLIENTWINDOW`, no further configuration.

This works quite well so far. The Beans get un-scoped if i go to another page or logout. One Problem I Experienced: 
When I open my details page in a new Browser tab, two new Beans are created, which is the expected Behavior. But when i close the tab, the Beans are still there. I guess the Server doesn't get notified when a tab get's closed.

1. Is there a built-in solution in deltaspike i can use to detect
   tab clsoes?
2. Is there a Timeout for Beans with @ViewAccessScoped (beside the Session-Timeout)?
3. If there isn't a bulit-in solution: How can i programmatically un-scope  my Beans? Preferably un-scope all Beans connected to that tab (=same Window-ID) (I'd detect the close my self with JavaScript and call a Bean-Method on close)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, as it's not possible to catch a "tab close" event in JS.
   See: [javascript detect browser close tab/close browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser)
2. It was available in CODI but it was not migrated to DeltaSpike.
   See: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DELTASPIKE-437
3. You can do it via the WindowContext API:

   ```
   @Inject private org.apache.deltaspike.core.spi.scope.window.WindowContext windowContext;

   public void closeIt() {
       windowContext.closeWindow("myWindowId");
   }
   ```